# Is there a way to drag and drop objects in AngularJS without generating an id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, drag-and-drop

One of the great aspects about AngularJS is the ability to work with elements without having to query the DOM to look them up by ID, class name, or attributes.  We shouldn't have to worry about how the DOM is setup.  Well, I'm attempting to implement a drag and drop directive for my chess game in an attempt to better my knowledge of AngularJS's directives and how they can communicate between directives.  I have my board all setup (and it looks pretty nice), and now I'm beginning the function parts.  The first thing I wanted to tackle was the drag-and-drop aspect.  So I've researched many implementations, and what I find people doing is creating a UUID (GUID) and applying element's ID in the link function.  That seems counter-intuitive to me, especially with the drastic changes coming down the road with AngularJS 2.0.  So I forced myself to start with two directives.

```
chessApp.directive('dropContainer', [function () {
    var bindings = {
        dragOverCss: '@',
        onDragOver: '&',
        onDrop: '&'
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: true,
        bindToController: bindings,
        controller: [function () {
            this.dragOverCallback = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (this.onDragOver)
                    this.onDragOver(e);
            }

            this.dropCallback = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (this.onDrop)
                    this.onDrop(e);
            }
        }],
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.on('onDragOver', ctrl.dragOverCallback);
            element.on('onDrop', ctrl.onDrop);
        }
    }
}]);
```

and

```
chessApp.directive('dragContainer', [function () {
    var bindings = {
        onDrag: '&'
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: true,
        controllerAs: 'dragContainerCtrl',
        bindToController: bindings,
        controller: [function () {
            if (!this.onDrag)
                this.onDrag = angular.noop;
        }],
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.attr('draggable', 'true');
            element.on('onDragStart', ctrl.onDrag);
        }
    }
}]);
```

I imagined being able to use them like so:

```
<div drop-container style="border: solid 1px black; height: 50px;"></div>
<span drag-container style="border: solid 1px black; background-color: red">Drag Me</span>
```

Then I got to thinking...once I drop in my dropContainer directive, how am I supposed to "grab" the element (and it's directive/controller) that's being dragged?  The possibility that comes to mind is by using a service somehow.  Am I heading down the right path or is there another away?

Edit: I should also mention that I know of the ability to json/stringify data, but in my case, I'm working with references and want to get the original object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using a parent directive to wrap everything and act as a facilitator for the move.